# ASP.NET listbox selected item change textbox text

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listbox

So I got a listbox with 5 different persons in it. And when I click on the first person in the list a text appears in a textbox. An if I click on another person, we get another text in the textbox etc.

Here is my list:

```
private List<string> personsList = new List<string>();

personsList.Add("Person1");
personsList.Add("Person2");
personsList.Add("Person3");
personsList.Add("Person4");
personsList.Add("Person5");

ListBoxPersons.DataSource = personsList;
ListBoxPersons.DataBind();
```

So, if I click of Person1 we get the text "Andersson" in the textbox. If we click on Person2 we get the text "Smith" in the textbox.

I've tried this:

```
foreach (ListItem item in ListBoxPersons.Items)
{
    if (item.Text == "Person1")
    {
        TextBoxPersons.Text = "Andersson";
    }
    else if (item.Text == "Person2")
    {
        TextBoxPersons.Text = "Smith";
    }
}
```

And so on, but that didn't work. I have tried quite a few other ways of doing it, but sadly no luck with that either.
This may seem silly, but it is just an exercise.

C# or JQuery works for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your `foreach` loop doesnt work because you are checking all the items in the listbox, not only the selected one. so for each of the persons you performing this check, and eventually the text will be the text of the last item in the list because thats the last item the foreach loop will reach

Comment: and if you want to change the text when you click the listbox items, you need to set the listbox's `AutoPostback="true"`

Comment: Yeah I have AutoPostback="true". Check my comment on sr28s answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code isn't checking what's currently selected, just each item in the list. You need to create a SelectedIndexChanged event to handle when you select something different. Something like this [example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Basically, add the event to your asp.net ListBox control and then create the event in your code behind with the same name something like this:

```
private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // Get the currently selected item in the ListBox. 
   string curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

   switch(curItem)
   {
       case "Person1":
           TextBoxPersons.Text = "Andersson";
       break;
       case "Person2":
           TextBoxPersons.Text = "Smith";
       break;
       //Add more cases and perhaps a default...
   }
}
```

***UPDATE***

Just saw the comments from @Banana and @PhilipB. As mentioned you need to ensure you wrap the listbox initialization in if(!IsPostback) in your Page_Load event to ensure you don't lose the fact you've selected an item.

Comment: Well I already had it in that event at least, just forgot to write that. I tried your code, but I get the exception "Objectreference is not an instance of an object" on the "string curItem = listBox1" line...

Comment: @PhilipB this probably happens because you re-initialize the listbox on every page load, so there is no selected item when this handler is being run. wrap your listbox initialization with `if(!IsPostBack)` and it will work

Comment: Thank you both sr28 and Banana! sr28 with the code, and Banana with the exception I got. Now it works :) Maybe you Banana can edit this answer with your IsPostBack comment so people in the future see it more easily?

Comment: @PhilipB if i edit his answer with new information, it might be flagged as conflicting with author's intent. but yes, sr28 should add this to the answer :)

Comment: @Banana Ah I see, well I guess he will see these comments then and act on it if he wants to :P

Answer (score 0):

The above code which @sr28 suggested works fine I have tried it.
This is the view:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">   </asp:ListBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

on pageload bind the listbox:
           `if (!IsPostBack)
          {
            personsList.Add("Person1");
            personsList.Add("Person2");
            personsList.Add("Person3");
            personsList.Add("Person4");
            personsList.Add("Person5");
            ListBox1.DataSource = personsList;
            ListBox1.DataBind();   
}`
```

And this on the onSelectedIndexChanged:

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        string curItem = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        switch (curItem)
        {
            case "Person1":
                TextBox1.Text = "Andersson";
                break;
            case "Person2":
                TextBox1.Text = "Smith";
                break;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code Behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> personsList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            personsList.Add("Andersson", "Person1");
            personsList.Add("Smith", "Person2");
            personsList.Add("Name 3", "Person3");
            personsList.Add("Name 4", "Person4");
            personsList.Add("Name 5", "Person5");

            ListBoxPersons.DataTextField = "Value";
            ListBoxPersons.DataValueField = "Key";
            ListBoxPersons.DataSource = personsList;
            ListBoxPersons.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void ListBoxPersons_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = ListBoxPersons.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Page

```
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxPersons" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBoxPersons_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:ListBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```